# Rowkey Search vs RowKeyRegexFilter

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I've been trying to build an API to retrieve data from my Big Data Table.

I've read the documentation that talks about structuring your row keys and how row key searches are always more efficient compared to filters because filters query the entire table then filter.

I have data coming in from machines in the field and am storing the data in Bigtable

My rowkey is structured like this:

{project}#{machine}#{aggregationType}#{ProductionSerial}#{timestamp}

AggregationType is to denote whether i want the raw value, the 1 minute average, the 10 minute average etc. I'm saving it all in the same table

Production serial - Overtime, the machine outputs products which monotonically increase in number, so like R001, R002, R003

So for example:

tu7#s777#raw#R001#20210113100040

tu7#s777#raw#R001#20210113101040

tu7#s777#raw#R001#20210113102040

tu7#s777#raw#R002#20210113102040

There are two ways I want to query and return the data, and hereby are my questions.

1. By Time Stamp

With this rowkey setup as above, I would use start_key and end_key to specify my query. However, I don't know what the production serial will be, is there a way I can use a wildcard? I understand this is possible by applying a filter using RowKeyRegexFilter but this is inefficient. Or am I wrong?

2. By Production Serial

This would be simple case again I would use start_key and end_key

Bear in mind, overtime, the database will get really large because of the amount of machines and the frequency of streaming data in. What would be the best way to do the query?

Comment: Is it possible for you to have 2 tables with rowkeys elements in different order ? Like for use-case 1, {reversed_timestamp}#{project}#... and for use-case 2 {production_serial]#{project}#.... With 2 tables, you can always use start_key and end_key to make queries (more efficient than filters).

Comment: It is possible, but its double the storage for the same data no? Wouldnt it be expensive to do so ?

Comment: You are correct. As you'd need to store the data in two separate tables, this will lead to an increase in your billing. But as adviced on the relevant section of the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#design_your_row_key_with_your_queries_in_mind) you basically can follow these two approaches: denormalization (as suggested by norbjd) or query and filter (which could lead to underperformance for the "Production Serial" queries).

Comment: In order to avoid costs to spiral out of control you could e.g. delete the second table after running the relevant queries you'd need to get the relevant insights of your application or after an X amount of days. Since data is redundant all the relevant information would still be stored on the first table. I think exploring [this docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series) in depth could help you in making the correct decision as per your application. Let me know if you find the information shared to be useful.

Comment: I am loading the data using dataflow. Do I need to make dataflow write to the two tables. Or....is there an easy way to copy an existing table to a new table, and change the rowkeys? Just curious.
Thanks for the answers btw, really sheds some light on the matter

Comment: You could run another Dataflow pipeline to create a replica table and change the key as described [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/optimal-performance-with-bigtable-changing-the-key-of-your-table-with-apache-beam-9139542a445e). This [post](https://medium.com/@philipp.schmiedel/how-to-update-row-keys-in-google-big-table-4db0c85e3be) that explains how to update row keys might also come in handy.

Comment: Thanks @DanielOcando for the info. you are a star!